# How to change PowerShell result behavior based on XML & CSV?

Tags: xml, powershell

Hi I have below script & when I am running this script its generating multiple XML based on one master XML now these xml have computer name info which should be updated in xml as below-

```
<ComputerName>Server1</ComputerName>
```

but showing as below which is not right format-

```
<ComputerName>Server1, server2, server3</ComputerName>
```

PS script as -

```
$template = Get-Content -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\MasterXML.xml' -Raw
$csv= Import-Csv 'C:\pscript\vj\CH21000546421_ProductID.csv'
Remove-Item 'C:\pscript\vj\dup.csv'
Remove-Item 'C:\pscript\vj\uniq.csv'


$csv |
Group-Object -Property ServerName |
Where-Object -FilterScript {
$_.Count -gt 1
} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\dup.csv' -NoTypeInformation



Import-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\dup.csv' | Group-Object ServerName | ForEach-Object {
# replace the placeholders in the template. Sort the numeric values for neatness as we go.
$template -replace '#Title#', (([int[]]$_.Group.IGPID | Sort-Object) -join ', ') -replace
'#computername#', "<ComputerName>$($_.Name)</ComputerName>" |
Set-Content -Path "C:\pscript\vj\$($_.Name).xml" -Encoding UTF8
}

$csv |
Group-Object -Property ServerName |
Where-Object -FilterScript {
$_.Count -lt 2
} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\uniq.csv' -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\uniq.csv' | Group-Object IGPID | ForEach-Object {
# replace the placeholders in the template. Sort the numeric values for neatness as we go.
$template -replace '#computername#',"<ComputerName>$(($_.Group.ServerName) -join ',')</ComputerName>" -replace
'#Title#', ($_.Name) |
Set-Content -Path "C:\pscript\vj\$($_.Name).xml" -Encoding UTF8

 }
```

I am sure below part is handling this comma separation, please help in how to update it so it will not break or effect code 1 in the script.

```
$template -replace '#computername#',"<ComputerName>$(($_.Group.ServerName) -join ',')</ComputerName>" -replace
```

Comment: Cleary the code was not written to do this. The issue is the `ForEach-Object` as is outputs a new file per every entry and is not written to appended strings to a single XML file.

Comment: Also, can you please provide your attempts to make the script work as you need? Otherwise it's a fully functional script.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your response ! yes script is working fine but the output is not correct or I would say not what I am expecting. I have no knowledge of scripting it was already in system but was not working the way it suppose to. I am playing with below bit - '#computername#',"<ComputerName>$(($_.Group.ServerName) -join ',')</ComputerName>" and this is the area where I am looking something to generate output as <ComputerName>Server1</ComputerName> not as <ComputerName>Server1, server2, server3</ComputerName>, I tried changing join by , to what I want but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to output an xml file for every server found in the 'CH21000546421_ProductID.csv' using a template, but having trouble with writing these out for the duplicate servernames.

If your template looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Servers>
  <Server title="#Title#">#computername#</Server>
</Servers>
```

and your input csv looks anything like this:

```
"IGPID","ServerName"
123,"Server1"
43,"Server2"
8,"Server3"
11,"Server1"
1,"Server1"
17,"Server3"
```

Then the below code should do what you want:

```
$template = Get-Content -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\MasterXML.xml' -Raw
$csv      = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\CH21000546421_ProductID.csv' | Group-Object -Property ServerName

# get the duplicate servernames
$dupes = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 }
# get the unique servernames
$uniq = $csv | Where-Object { $_.Count -lt 2 }
            
# save this as new csv files
$dupes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\dup.csv' -NoTypeInformation
$uniq  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\pscript\vj\uniq.csv' -NoTypeInformation

# $dupes is already grouped by servername
$dupes | ForEach-Object {
    # remember you're iterating Groups with multiple items here!
    foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        $template -replace '#Title#', $item.IGPID -replace '#computername#', "<ComputerName>$($item.ServerName)</ComputerName>" |
        # write an xml for each of the duplicates. By appending the IGPID to the name of the file
        Set-Content -Path "C:\pscript\vj\$($item.ServerName)_$($item.IGPID).xml" -Encoding UTF8
    }
}

# $uniq is already grouped by servername
$uniq | ForEach-Object {
    # or use -replace '#computername#', "<ComputerName>$($_.Group[0].ServerName)</ComputerName>"
    $template -replace '#Title#', $_.Group[0].IGPID -replace '#computername#', "<ComputerName>$($_.Name)</ComputerName>" |
    # write an xml for each of the unique servers.
    Set-Content -Path "C:\pscript\vj\$($_.Name).xml" -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Now you have several xml files, one for each server. The servers that were found as duplicate all have xml files named `<servername>_<id>.xml`.
The unique servers have files called `<servername.xml>`

Demo content of 'Server1_123.xml' (one of the duplicates)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Servers>
  <Server title="123"><ComputerName>Server1</ComputerName></Server>
</Servers>
```

Demo content of the only unique server in the input file 'Server2.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Servers>
  <Server title="43"><ComputerName>Server2</ComputerName></Server>
</Servers>
```